# Insert multiple records with a number range in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

How would one add multiple records in a DB Table for numerical values. I have a table called Issue (Customer, Issue Date, Sealno.) where a user fills in the sealno. of the first seal and sealno. of the last seal. The first seal and the last is the range. In the table record of the first seal to the last will be filled all with the same Customer name and Issue Date.

My DB name is Seals;Table name Issue. The below macro is initiated by a save button in the DB Form;

```
                 Private Sub Command17_Click()
                 Dim rsIssue  As DAO.Recordset
                   Dim Seal As Date
                   Set rsIssue = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * 
                     From Issue")
                   Seal = Me!Seal1.Value
                   While DateDiff("d", Seal, Me!Seal2.Value) >= 0
                   rsIssue.AddNew
                   rsIssue!SealNo.Value = Me!SealNo.Value
                   rsIssue!Customer.Value = Me!Customer.Value
                   rsIssue!Seal1.Value = Seal
                   rsIssue.Update

                   Seal = DateAdd("d", 1, Seal)
           Wend
        rsIssue.Close
        Set rsIssue = Nothing
         End Sub
```

The code however does not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My DB name is Seals;Table name Issue. The below macro is initiated by a save button in the DB Form;Private Sub Command17_Click()
Dim rsIssue  As DAO.Recordset
Dim Seal As Date
Set rsIssue = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From Issue")
Seal = Me!Seal1.Value
While DateDiff("d", Seal, Me!Seal2.Value) >= 0
rsIssue.AddNew
rsIssue!SealNo.Value = Me!SealNo.Value
rsIssue!Customer.Value = Me!Customer.Value
rsIssue!Seal1.Value = Seal
rsIssue.Update
       
Seal = DateAdd("d", 1, Seal)
Wend
rsIssue.Close
Set rsIssue = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Code seems OK, so what does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Hi, the code does not work. No multiple entries are added to the table Issue

Comment: My aim is to add a range of seals (from Seal1 to Seal2) in the table as multiple entries. However, with the code, only one entry is made to the DB: being the first seal no. (Seal1).

Comment: Sounds like Seal1 equals Seal2.

Comment: @Gustav Who can I tinker it to work? Is it the code line While DateDiff("d", Seal, Me!Seal2.Value) >= 0 ? Please help

Comment: Again, code seems OK. So, I guess, _Seal1_ and _Seal2_ don't hold the values, you may think they do.